# Inner / outer model

Tags: model, structural-equation-modeling, measurement

i have created a SEM model and want to know while reporting which part should be treated as Structural model and which portion as  and outer / measurement model . Whether i should take portion A or portion B

thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not absolutely clear to me what B involves. But the structural model is the relationships between the latent variables, and the measurement model is the relationships between the measuremed variables and the latent variables.

So B is the closest to the structural model, but it l0oks like it includes csome measurement parts.

However, unless the measurement arrows are in the wrong direction, that's a very strange model. (Also, does commitment have any indicators?